# Send POST data in Android

Tags: android, json, apache, postgresql, gson

I'm trying to send POST data in Android. On internet I find some codes with Apache, but the codes were deprecated.

I need to send the values bellow to my web service and than register on PostgreSQL

```
edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
edtLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLogin);
edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
```

If someone knows how to do that, can be with GSON or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) with Gson.
Add those libraries to your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

First create a singleton class with the retrofit instance

```
public class Api {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://yourApiBaseUrl.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getInstance(){
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Then define your model, I assume is something like this:

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("Login")
    private String login;

    @SerializedName("Password")
    private String password;

    public User(...){
         //Constructor
    }

}
```

After that, you are ready to create your calls to the api. Create an interface to define the methods of your api. I assume your post method return the posted user. You will send all the data encapsulated in the user model, inside the body of the http request:

```
public interface UserService {

    @POST("yourPostUrl")
    Call<User> postUser(@Body User user);

}
```

Now it's time to do the POST. Create a method where you want to perform the post, just like this:

```
private void postUser(String edtName, String edtEmail, String edtLogin, String edtPassword){

        UserService service = Api.getInstance().create(UserService.class);
        Call<User> userCall = service.postUser(new User(edtName, edtEmail, edtLogin, edtPassword));
        userCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                } 
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}
```

And that's all, hope it helps.

For more information visit the [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) website and read the tutorial.

Comment: What link I need to put here: public static final String BASE_URL = "http://yourApiBaseUrl.com/"; ?

Comment: And this line I didn't understand: IUserService service = Api.getInstance().create(IUserService.class);

Comment: Imagine your post method url is http://mywebapi.com/users, then your base url is http://mywebapi.com/

then,  in your interface, in the post method you should write
@POST("users")
Call<User> postUser(@Body User user);  

I updated my answer, the correct line for your second question is:
UserService service = Api.getInstance().create(IUserService.class);

Comment: I'm sorry, the correct line is UserService service = Api.getInstance().create(UserService.class);

Comment: I corrected the code... then the following message show up: NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Comment: My complete URL is (localhost): http://172.168.1.102:8080/Party/webresources/party/user/insert